# Reunion of disjoint stable sets in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I need to prove that given a graph G=(V,E), |V| = n and for any v in V with deg(v) at most k then  there are up to $2k+1$ disjoint stable sets (let's say $S_1$ ... $S_{2k+1}$) and their reunion is V.

Now, I suppose that in a coloring the vertices from a stable set could be the same color because the vertices are non-adjacent. And since the sets are disjoint we could say that each set needs a different color. So then the chromatic number of the original graph is $2k+1$ (or at least $2k+1$).

Now, I know that this is one way to look at the problem, but I have no idea how to connect that to the original hypothesis or how to start a demonstration from the hypothesis to the conclusion or from the conclusion to the hypothesis.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (As with that question, I wonder if there is not some hypothesis you've forgotten to include, since otherwise $2k+1$ is way bigger than necessary.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I don't think there is any hypothesis I forgot to include. Why would be 2k+1 bigger than necessary?

Comment: Because (as the answer in the linked question points out) if the maximum degree is $k$ then the chromatic number is at most $k+1$ (and $k+1$ sets are enough).